# on click swatch image simple product id not change

Tags: php, magento, magento2

i am using magento 2.1.7.

i made configurable product with 3 simple products, Simple product are used as a color swatch.

Now on frontend, when i choose 1st swatch than it is working fine. but while i choose 2nd swatch it shows 1st swatch's main image.

i directly debug this in `vendor/magento/module-swatches/Controller/Ajax/Media.php` and `vendor/magento/module-swatches/Helper/Data.php`

i just try to debug code. so i notice that it is not changing simple product id.

**DEBUG CODE**

**request 1st swatch**

```
 product_id:5514
 attributes[color]:269
 additional[]:
 isAjax:true
```

**response 1st swatch**

```
['simple_product_id'] => string(4) "5523"
```

**request 2nd swatch**

```
 product_id:5514
 attributes[color]:270
 additional[]:
 isAjax:true
```

**response 2nd swatch**

```
['simple_product_id'] => string(4) "5523"
```

i am getting similar simple product id's it should be like `5524` not `5523` for 2nd swatch

Why this is happening?

Looking for Help!

Comment: please share the code

Comment: @AdityaSingh it is a default behaviors i just update my question. it is a fresh magento installation